# insert in C++ vector

Tags: c++

I want to insert a bit from a bitset in the beginning of a vector. I am having a hard time understanding how to do that. Here is how I think I can do it:

```
keyRej.insert(x, inpSeq[0]);
```

I don't know what to put in the place of x?

Comment: If inserting at the beginning is common and you have control over the type, you might consider replacing your `std::vector` with a `std::deque`.

Comment: Related: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't know what to put in the place of x?

An iterator to the position you want to insert in:

```
keyRej.insert(keyRej.begin(), inpSeq[0]);
```

Semantically, the inserted element goes before the iterator passed as first argument. But this will result in all elements of the vector having to be moved across one position, and may also incur a re-allocation of the vector's internal data storage block. It also means that all iterators or references to the vector's elements are invalidated.

See this reference for [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) for more information.

Note that there are containers, such as [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), for which appending elements to the front is cheap, and reference (but not iterator) validity is maintained.

Comment: I am not sure what .begin() will do, I want to but the first bit of inpSeq in the vector, then under a loop put other bits using push_back after that inpSeq bit.

Comment: @MohamedAhmed Your question doesn't say anything about a loop or pushing elements into the back of the vector. I have answered the question you asked.

Comment: If this operation has to be done to often, it may be better to either change your code to append at the end (if append/erase is always done on the same side of the vector) or to move to a data structure that has better performance characteristics in insertion at both ends (like a deque).

Answer (score 3):

x is an iterator according to the documentation you probably read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert), the new object is insert just before it.

```
keyRej.insert(keyRej.begin(), inpSeq[0]);
```